# Prolog parallelism

Tags: parallelism, prolog

Are there any prolog interpreters that can functionally decompose your 'programs' in order to improve efficiency?

I know there's been research on prolog interpreters that reach near-C speeds through parallelism (the kind that a typical C programmer can't "see").  Does anyone know more about this topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Some starting points**

You might want to look into this research paper: http://www.mendeley.com/research/implementation-parallel-prolog-interpreter-multiprocessors/

Also, this Prolog on Python proof of concept paper has some interesting leads: http://www.mendeley.com/research/a-prolog-interpreter-in-python/